# Taking Xcode 40 seconds to run app on iPad 2 after updating to Xcode to 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, debugging, delay

After updating to Xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0.1 it's taking 40+ seconds to run and connect to debugger with a brand new empty project on an iPad 2.  Same application running on an iPhone 5 and takes 7 seconds to connect to the debugger.  Simulator works fine.

If I switch from Launch Automatically to Wait for app to Launch, it still takes 40+ seconds for Xcode to be ready to wait for the app to launch.

What I've tried
-Searching forums for an answer :).
-Deleting DerivedData
-Deleting and creating new development profiles
-Turning off iAd
-Rebooting mac, and device
-Switching out cable
-Trying different projects, creating a new project
-Changing the debugger from LLDB to GDB
-Console log doesn't show any strange errors

The only next step I can think of is to reinstall Xcode and wipe the iPad 2.  Hoping someone has run into this and has a better option.  Thanks in advance.